# Multiple user deletion with checkbox doesn't work

Tags: mysql, sql-delete

I want to delete multiple users from db table with checkboxes at once. But my code doesn't work correctly
**index.php**

```
<?php 
require 'db.php';   
$query="SELECT * FROM usr_table";
$result = $db->query($query) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
$num=mysqli_num_rows($result) or die(mysqli_errno());
if ($result) {
    echo '
    <form method="post" action="delete.php">
    <table id="list">   
            while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
        $id = $row->id;
        $fullname = $row->fullname;
        $dob = $row->dob;
        $phone= $row->phone;
        $adress= $row -> adress;
        $school = $row->school;
echo '<tr>
<td>'.$id.'</td>
<td>'.$fullname.'</td>
<td>'.$dob.'</td>
<td>'.$phone.'</td>
<td>'.$adress.'</td>
<td>'.$school.'</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" id="checkbox[]"  method="post" value=$id />
</tr>';
    }

    // when the loop is complete, close off the list.
    echo "</table><p><input id='delete' type='submit' class='button' name='delete' value='Delete Selected Items'/></p></form>";
    }
?>
```

**delete.php**

```
<?php

    require 'db.php';
    $delete=$_GET['delete'];

    if($delete) // from button name="delete"
    {
        $checkbox = $_GET['checkbox']; //from name="checkbox[]"
        $countCheck = count($_GET['checkbox']);

        for($i=0;$i<$countCheck;$i++)
        {
            $del_id  = $checkbox[$i];
            $sql = "DELETE from usr_table where id = '$del_id'";
            $result = $db->query($sql) or die(mysqli_error($db));

        }
            if($result)
        {   
                header('Location: index.php');
            }
            else
            {
                echo "Error: ".mysqli_error($db);
            }
    }

?>
```

**db.php**

```
<?php
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'user' ,'pass', 'table') or die(mysqli_errno());
$db->query("SET names UTF8") or die(mysqli_errno());
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) { 
$_POST[$key] = mysqli_real_escape_string($value);
}
?>
```

Please help! It doesn't work
**HTML version**

```
<form method="post" action="delete.php">
    <table id="list">   
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th width="5%">ID</th>

                    <th width="35%">Ad və soyad</th>
                    <th width="15%">Təvəllüd</th>
                    <th width="15%">Telefon</th>
                    <th width="20%">Ünvan</th>
                    <th width="5%">Məktəb</th>
                    <th width="5%">#</th>

                </tr>
            </thead><tr>
<td>20</td>
<td>Tural Teyyuboglu</td>
<td>1992-06-09</td>
<td>4940301</td>
<td>Baki Yasamal Zergerpalan</td>
<td>189</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" id="checkbox[]"  method="post" value="20 "/>

</tr><tr>
<td>22</td>
<td></td>
<td>1992-06-09</td>
<td>0</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" id="checkbox[]"  method="post" value="22 "/>
</tr><tr>
<td>23</td>
<td>Tural Turik</td>
<td>1992-06-09</td>

<td>4940301</td>
<td>Bakı Yasamal Zərgerpalan</td>
<td>189</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" id="checkbox[]"  method="post" value="23 "/>
</tr><tr>
<td>24</td>
<td>Tural Əliyev</td>
<td>1992-06-09</td>
<td>4940301</td>
<td>Bakı Y </td>

<td></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" id="checkbox[]"  method="post" value="24 "/>
</tr><tr>
<td>25</td>
<td>Zammbbb</td>
<td>1992-06-09</td>
<td>4940301</td>
<td>Bakı Uadnf` skbnfias</td>
<td>189</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" id="checkbox[]"  method="post" value="25 "/>
</tr><tr>

<td>26</td>
<td>Tural Əliyev</td>
<td>1992-06-09</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>  </td>
<td></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" id="checkbox[]"  method="post" value="26 "/>
</tr></table><p><input id='delete' type='submit' class='button' name='delete' value='Delete Selected Items'/></p></form>                </td>
            </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: You might want to check the generated HTML for index.php, and include that as code in your question. Judging from the syntax color coding, the HTML text is mixed up with PHP code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things wrong here..

1) Your form `method="POST"`. In your delete.php, you are using `$_GET['checkbox'].`

Use `$_POST['checkbox']` instead. (`$_GET['delete']` needs to be `$_POST['delete']`).

2) You're echoing PHP code:

```
if ($result) {

echo '
<form method="post" action="delete.php">
<table id="list">   
        while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
    $id = $row->id;
    $fullname = $row->fullname
```

You need to end your echo statement before continuing with PHP code:

```
if ($result) {

    echo<<<formheader
    <form method="post" action="delete.php">
    <table id="list">   
formheader;

    while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
        $id = $row->id;
        $fullname = $row->fullname
```

3 & 4) Put quotes around your values in your input element, like so:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" id="checkbox" value="$id" />
```

And if you're going to echo like that, then escape your double quotes since it is in an echo statement:

```
<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"checkbox[]\" id=\"checkbox\" value=\"$id\" />
```

5) Your `$_POST` sanitizing is what is emptying your multi-dimensional $_POST['checkbox'] array from `db.php`.

When I remove this from `db.php`

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) { 
    $_POST[$key] = mysqli_real_escape_string($value);
}
```

Then your `print_r($_POST)` should display your values. Assuming everything else is alright, that should work. However, you'll need to reconsider how you sanitize your POST variables.

Comment: inserted print_r($_POST) at the top result: Array ( [checkbox] => [delete] => )

Comment: I hope that was understandable. Seems choppy.

Comment: tried all things that you wrote. no succes. i didn't echo while. copy-paste error))